# Why Class<T> and Constructor<T> are typed but Field and Method are not? In java

Tags: java, generics

In java, `Class<T>` and `Constrcutor<T>` are generic, but `Field` and `Method` are not, why?

`Class.newInstance()` and `Constructor.newInstance()` return `T`, but `Field.get()` and `Method.invoke()` return `Object`.

Why not make `Field` as `Field<T>` and `Method` as `Method<T>` then they can return `T` not `Object`?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking since fields can be generic and methods can have generic parameters. Please fix your typos (you've got a few there) and if possible, clarify your question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I mean, class `Class<T>` and `Constrcutor<T>` typed parameter `T`, but class `Field` and `Method` have not.

Comment: What would the type T of a `Method<T>` be? The return type? the first parameter? there is no variadic type parameter

Comment: @Rubydesic that's enough. `newInstance` method returns `T` and its parameters are `Object...`

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess I would say that it's because there's no way to obtain a reference to a `Method<T>` or `Field<T>` without casting it yourself. You can get a `Class<T>` by using a class literal (e.g., `String.class` produces a `Class<String>`), and you can get a `Constructor<T>` out of that class, (`#getConstructor`), but Java has no `Field` literal or `Method` literal, so the only way to get a type parameter out of a method or field would be to produce it out of thin air with a type cast.